# pip install psycopg2 blocks

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

i'm installing the psycopg2 package for python. i'm doing:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

and i get the following

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
Downloading psycopg2-2.5.4.tar.gz (682kB): 682kB downloaded
    Running setup.py (path:/Users/<username>/.virtualenvs/<virtualenvname>/build/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2
     building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
     cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090305 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
```

and it just blocks indefinitely..

ideas?

specs:
MAC OSX 10.9.4
python 2.7.5
pip 1.5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make sure I had python-dev, and I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode and the install worked.